# tastypie: update resource from within another unrelated resource

Tags: django, resources, tastypie

I am new to tastypie, I want to update an unrelated resource from within another resource;
use case: I create a user, after that I want to update another table (resource) with a value I got from the current request:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        ...

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        bundle.data[ 'is_active' ] = 0
        bundle.data[ 'is_staff' ] = 0
        bundle = super( UserResource, self ).obj_create( bundle, **kwargs )
        bundle.obj.set_password( sPassword )
        bundle.obj.save()
        # here I want to set a flag in an already existing but unrelated resource
        # sg like : Fancy.obj_update( -> set flag = 2 where token = bundle.data[ 'token' ] )
        # I guess its a question how the "bundle" looks like, right?
        return bundle
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to update a table can't you use the ORM directly? Sorry if I got this wrong, just my initial reaction.

Comment: hmm you might be right, I could rethink my models and use ORM... I will let you know how it went